# Django haystack boost (document=true) field (Solr backend)

Tags: django, solr, django-views, django-haystack

So I have

```
class ProductIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
  text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
  region = fields.MultiValueField(model_attr='region')
  condition = fields.MultiValueField(model_attr='condition')
```

Inside the (`document=True`) field I have

```
{{ object.name }}
{{ object.description }}
```

How can I boost the `object.name` field ? Do I have to create separate `name` field ?

Also is there possibility to have my SearchQuerySet() to use both `SearchQuerySet().order_by('-created_on')` + use the boost option on the `name` field , so the result would be:

1. First list the objects that have matches in the title
2. Than list the other objects ordered by date